# How can I get a External Samsung SSD to work with Xbox One

Tags: solid-state-drive, xbox-one

A new External SSD from Samsung 256gb shows up as 128gb media only on Xbox One. Formatting option not available.

Comment: "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User."

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to solve this from the Xbox One only.

Connect it to a mac or pc and run. It again shows up as 128gb.

On the drive there is an app called `Samsung Portable SSD`.
Run it.

Select any name (name will be erased later), and click `no` on encryption.

Remove drive from computer and connect to Xbox One.

The Xbox will now recognize the drive and allow you to format it.